# Couldn't make it close the overlay and popup

Tags: jquery, fancybox

JQuery

```
jQuery ( function ( $ ) {
$(".fancybox")
.fancybox({
  type: 'ajax',
  autoHeight: false,
  minHeight: 900,
  width: 965,
  autoSize: false,
  autoCenter: true,
  fitToView: false,
  topRatio: 0,
  scrolling: 'visible',
  arrows: false,
  closeBtn: false,
  autoPlay: false,
  wrapCSS: 'pop-wrapper',
  helpers:{
    overlay : {
        closeClick : true,
        speedOut   : 200,
        showEarly  : false,
        locked     : true,
      }
  }
});

  $('i.icn-close-overlay').click(function(){
    $('.fancybox').close();
    $('wrapper').find('.fancybox-overlay').remove();
  });
});
```

HTML

```
 <div class="pop-header">
  <a class="fancybox" href="javascript:void(0);"><i class="icn-close-overlay"></i></a>
</div><!--end #header-->
```

The issue is that I couldn't use:

```
$.fancybox.close();
```

So I resort to that:

```
 $('i.icn-close-overlay').click(function(){
    $('.fancybox').close();
    $('wrapper').find('.fancybox-overlay').remove();
  });
});
```

The problem is now that the fancybox popup can be closed, but the fancybox overlay doesn't disappear upon close. I am not sure why it is not working :(

Help appreciated.

**UPDATED**
tried: JQuery.fancybox.close(); in a herf tag, but error shows undefined method of close. It worked but after some tweaks, it stopped working. Any idea why?

Comment: are you sure this is the right code? cause `$('wrapper')` will return a js error since it is neither a selector or tag name. Also, where does fancybox get the content from? since you have `href="javascript:void(0);"` ... and last, why you can't use `$.fancybox.close();`? you wouldn't need to resort to anything else otherwise

Comment: @JFK - I did mention that I tried $.fancybox.close() but it wouldn't close overlay after the popup is closed. I replaced herf="jQuery.fancybox.close();" instead and it works. thanks